# From this php coding i want to get the values of checkboxes along with the regno. and inserted to database(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

The values in this table has been generated from database see attached Image. Now what i need to get the values from the check boxes in the table along with the regno(register number) or name.

```
 <form role="form" method="post">
          <label class="attendance"><strong>Date:</strong></label>
          <strong>
          <input  name="date" id="date" /></strong>
        </div>
        <table align="left" width="100%">
        <tr>
        <th>Rollno</th>
        <th>Regno</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM student where course='M.Sc.Software Systems' and year='4' ";
 $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {                  
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['rno'];?></td>   // values of rollno from database
    <td><?php echo $rows['regno']; ?></td>  // values of regno from database
    <td><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour1" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour2" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour3" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour4" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour5" value="1" />   
    </td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>
  <button name='insert' type="submit" class="contact">Submit</button>
  </form>
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['insert'])){
        $regno = $rows['regno1'];
        $hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];
        $hour2 = $_POST['hour2'];
        $hour3 = $_POST['hour3'];
        $hour4 = $_POST['hour4'];
        $hour5 = $_POST['hour5'];


        $query2 = "INSERT INTO attendance (regno,hour1,hour2,hour3,hour4,hour5) VALUES ('$regno','$hour1','$hour2','$hour3','$hour4','$hour5')";
        $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
        $message="Successfully Added";
        echo $message;
        mysql_close($connect_mysql);

        }   
        ?>
```

Comment: use intput type `hidden` along with each row

Comment: Can you post more code thna what you've posted? It's an incomplete fragement as is (starting with '?>') What you'll likely want to do is use an inline if statement to add the "checked" keyword like: <input type="checkbox" name="hour1" value="1" <? echo ($rows['hour1'] == 1 ? "checked" : "") ?> > (untested code)

Comment: Give same name to checkboxes with array like hour[]

Comment: i am a beginner i dont no much about this

Comment: i tried hour[] but not able to get regno or name

Comment: can you show your code from starting from <form> tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :-

```
<td><?php echo $rows['rno'];?></td>   // values of rollno from database
        <td><?php echo $rows['regno']; ?></td>  // values of regno from database
        <td><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="regno" value="<?php echo $rows['regno']; ?>"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour[]" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour[]" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour[]" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour[]" value="1"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hour[]" value="1" />
```

Value you will get in post(if you have used that)

```
$_POST["regno"] for registeration number.
```

and `$_POST["hour"]` for checkboxes values.

Comment: please tell me how get value from this array?

Comment: but i has a problem it get input of last regno.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: There are many regno. such as 11mss001 to 11mss008. The value 11mss008 is only inserted to database

Comment: you want to store all regno ?

Comment: i want to store the particular regno of the checkboxes.

Comment: Actually this is an attendance system, where checkbox1 is hour 1 similarly hour2,3,4,5...  so on marking the checkbox the regno along with the hour should be stored

Comment: you can get regno from last id inserted

Comment: so, what is the problem then ?

Comment: if i show screen shot you will be able to understand my problem. So please tell me a method to show my screen shot

Comment: you need to have permission for that

Comment: using any of social media.please...!

Comment: you can post on fb in PHP group.